# SP 2103 Form Headers Above Fields: Need Equals === Not Contains (no Infopath)

Tags: jquery, form

I use JQuery to add headers above specific fields in my forms, but it uses "contains" to locate fields.

I need code to locate fields by an exact match on the field name or ===.  I need help to rework my JQ.
(Note: I DO NOT have Infopath available)

Example:

Header code using "contains":

`$('<h2>Contact Information</h2>').insertBefore($('h3:contains("First Name")').parent().parent());`

I am trying to achieve similar matching ( === ) as in this code I use to hide fields:

`$('nobr').filter(function () { return $(this).text() === 'First Name' }).closest('tr').hide();`

Thank you, as always!

Comment: Something like this should work: $('<h2>Some header</h2>').insertBefore($('nobr').filter(function () { return $(this).text() === 'First Name' }))

Comment: Damjan, Thank you for this. This is close but it pushes the FormLabel (left) down, but not the FormBody (right).

Comment: Then something like this should do the trick (replaced h2 with span and added a space behind text): $('<span>Some header </span>').insertBefore($('nobr').filter(function () { return $(this).text() === 'First Name' }));

Comment: Still running into formatting issues.  I added my code to this to help describe the difference. Even with CSS formatting on h2's, your header is at the bottom left of the formlabel of the radio buttons on the right formbody.

```('<h2>Header using Contains</h2>').insertBefore($('h3:contains("Choice1")').parent().parent());
$('<h2>Damjan Header</h2>').insertBefore($('nobr').filter(function () { return $(this).text() === 'Choice2' }));
$('<h2>Another Header using Contains</h2>').insertBefore($('h3:contains("Field_1")').parent().parent());
 ```